# Can't call object from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class, object

I have a table view with expanding cells. The expanding cells come from a xib file. In the class of the table is where all of the code is that controls the expansion and pulling data from plist. I'm trying to add a close button but only want it to show when the cell is expanded. As it stands, I can't reference the button to hide it because it's in another class. Here is how I am trying to access it:

```
import UIKit

class SecondPolandViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var customTableViewCell:CustomTableViewCell? = nil
    var items = [[String:String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        **REFERENCING CLASS** 

        customTableViewCell = CustomTableViewCell()

        let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.items = loadPlist()
    }

    func loadPlist()->[[String:String]]{
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PolandResourceList", ofType: "plist")

        return NSArray.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!)) as! [[String:String]]
    }

    var selectedIndex:IndexPath?
    var isExpanded = false

    func didExpandCell(){
        self.isExpanded = !isExpanded
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndex!], with: .automatic)
    }
}

extension SecondPolandViewController:UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    ***HIDING BUTTON***

    let button = customTableViewCell?.closeButton
    button?.isHidden = true

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        self.didExpandCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let item = self.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = item["title"]
        cell.shortLabel.text = item["short"]
        cell.otherImage.image = UIImage.init(named: item["image"]!)
        cell.thumbImage.image = UIImage.init(named: item["image"]!)
        cell.longLabel.text = item["long"]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath{
            //return self.view.frame.size.height * 0.6
            return 400
        }

        return 110
        //return height * 0.2
    }
}
```

This does not hide it though.

Here is the xib that I am calling from if it helps. It is probably simple, I am just a newly self taught developer.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var otherImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thumbImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shortLabel: UILabel!
    //@IBOutlet weak var longLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var longLabel: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        //let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        //let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        //thumbImage.frame.size.width = height * 0.19
        //thumbImage.frame.size.height = height * 0.19
    }
}
```

[image: How it is now with circle that should be hidden. It's just an image not a button]

[image]

Comment: your getting the button in top of the extension and set it to hidden? Does this compile? Well, would set the button hidden in the cellForRow atIndexPat func, if indexPath is not the same as selected one. This should doe the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that you just need to add these lines into `cellForRowAt:indexPath` method:

```
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
  cell.closeButton.isHidden = false
} else {
  cell.closeButton.isHidden = true
}
```

You may add them right before `return` line

Comment: Thanks. Instead on that I had to use  if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath {
            cell.closeButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.closeButton.isHidden = true
            
        }
         Works now.

Answer (score 0):

The normal iOS answer for this is a delegate, but you could get away with a simple closure in this case.

In `CustomTableViewCell`, add

```
public var closeTapped: ((CustomTableViewCell) -> ())?
```

Then in that class, when close is tapped, call

```
self.closeTapped?(self)
```

In the VC, in cellForRowAt,

```
cell.closeTapped = { cell in 
    // do what you want with the VC
}
```

For delegates, this might help: https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

The quick answer to why to prefer delegates over the closure is that its a handy way to group a bunch of these together.  It's what UITableViewDelegate is (which you are using). Also, it's a common iOS idiom.

I wrote about this here: https://app-o-mat.com/post/how-to-pass-data-back-to-presenter for a similar situation (VC to VC communication)

Comment: i think he wanted to hide the cancelButton if the cell is not expanded.

Comment: Whatever they need to do, they can do in that closure

Comment: but what do you do with the fiest state? When everything is closed. There is no func, that will show the button

Comment: @Lou Franco  I cant get that to work. I added images if it helps. The first image is the way it is now. The close image always appears. The second image with the cell expanded is when I want it to appear. Until then, it should stay hidden. Note** The image is not a button. The whole cell triggers the action. The image is just an "illusion" to help them see what to do.